# Evaluate a limit involving powers of $2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> Evaluate the following limit: $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left( \sum_{k=1}^n2^\frac{n}{k} \right)}{n}$$

After using Cesaro-Stolz, I obtained $$L=\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln \frac{2^{n+1}+2^\frac{n+1}{2}+\dots+2^\frac{n+1}{n+1}}{2^n+2^\frac{n}{2}+\dots+2^\frac{n}{n}}=\ln \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{2^{n+1}+2^\frac{n+1}{2}+\dots+2^\frac{n+1}{n+1}}{2^n+2^\frac{n}{2}+\dots+2^\frac{n}{n}}$$ and I feel that the last limit must be $2$, but I couldn't prove it... I tried to use the sandwich theorem, but didn't get tight enough bounds

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can sandwich it
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left( 2^n \right)}{n}\le\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left( \sum_{k=1}^n2^\frac{n}{k} \right)}{n}\le \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left(2\cdot 2^n \right)}{n}\\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\ln 2\le\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\ln\left( \sum_{k=1}^n2^\frac{n}{k} \right)}{n}\le \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {(n+1)\ln 2}n$$
To get $L=\ln 2$

Where the first inequality just neglects all terms in the sum after the first and the second recognizes that after the first you have $n-1$ terms all (once $n$ gets large enough) less than $\frac {2^n}n$